# Issue with Updating Pick list Values through Metadata API in Apex Class

Tags: picklist, metadata-api

**What I have done :** Installed repository from GIT HUB In my Personal org https://githubsfdeploy.herokuapp.com/app/githubdeploy/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Created a custom controller and method : Inside method getting

> Variable does not exist: picklist

in this line

```
customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(newPicklistvalue);
```

Apex method:

```
private void addPicklistValue(MetadataService.CustomField customField, string picklistValue) {

    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();

    metadataservice.PicklistValue newPicklistvalue = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    newPicklistvalue.fullName= picklistValue;
    newPicklistvalue.default_x = false;



    customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(newPicklistvalue);

    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> {customField });

    refreshFields(customField);
}
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to access a property of the [`CustomField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) Metadata API entity, `picklist`, that is deprecated and unavailable in current API versions. From the linked Metadata API reference for `CustomField`:

> `picklist`: (**Deprecated**. Use this field in API version 37.0 and earlier only. In later versions, use `valueSet` instead.)

For this reason, you will not find it in current versions of `apex-mdapi`. Presumably you're working from sample code or examples that are out of date.

As is common when working with the Metadata API, you'll have to do some legwork to understand the complex data structures that are in use. The `ValueSet` type and its nested `ValueSetValuesDefinition` type are documented in the [Metadata Field Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm?search_text=valueset) documentation.

In the `apex-mdapi` library, you'll find the definition of the `ValueSet` class inside [`MetadataService.cls`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L6826).

That's what you'll need to use to make your updates.